# how to disable owa redirect url in href in email body

Tags: c#, gmail, outlook-web-app

When I am sending an email with email body includes href in html format from email/yahoo to Outlook Web Access, the owa redirect URL is appended with href URL.

My URL is:

```
http://web1.com
```

and when sending the email body like :

```
<a href="http://web1.com">click her</a>
```

, the owa URL is appended with href URL like below,

```
  https://owa1/owa/redir.aspx?C=.....URL=http://web1.com
```

How I prevent the outlook web access URL `https://owa1/owa/redir.aspx?C=` append with actual URL?

Comment: Outlook Web Access? Why is this question tagged for *gmail*?

Comment: i included owa as well in tag.

Comment: Did you try this link: https://www.google.com/?q=outlook+web+access+redir ?

Comment: this search providing different results. I'm asking to remove the outlook web access url append with actual url in href and not for asking to disable ssl settings